# Users Getting IIS Home Screen Instead of Home page

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, central-administration, iis

I have one user which is getting the IIS home landing page instead of our SharePoint home page.  When I log onto her from a different machine everything seems to be working fine. If she types in `ourpage/SitePages/Home.aspx` it works too. This has just happened within the last 14 hours or so.  Has anyone come across this problem before?

No one else seems to be having an issue.  Chrome does not give her this problem only IE.

Comment: Could be a history or cache problem? did you tried to clean it all?

Comment: I tried clearing out her cache but it is still doing it.  I am wondering if the cache issue is on the server itself, but she seems to be the only one with the issue.

Comment: Did you try to trace the request using Fiddler or another low level trace like WireShark, maybe this could give you some advice about the problem...

Comment: try a nslookup and then test the DNS. afterwards, try Fiddler and see what the redirects might be

Comment: Can you check the host file (C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts) on that machine to see if there is any localhost redirect.

Answer (score 1):

Just for others who might come across this, try a full refresh by pressing CTRL+F5.  This is likely a cache issue, especially if it only occurs in one browser.  This happened to me after the Default Website was started while the Portal Web App was stopped and I hit the site.  Once I stopped the Default Website and started the Portal Web App, I was still seeing the IIS Welcome screen.  CTRL+F5 forced IE to reload the site.

Answer (score 0):

Since the new version of IE, it cache all get requests. So that is possible that the site is already cached. Try to empty it and then it will be working.